# Decoding and playing aac-eld, regular static and oddities

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, cscore

Sample: 
https://soundcloud.com/michael-rogers-43/440hz-scratchy

I am using ffmpeg to decode some raw aac-eld frames and it seems whenever I try to play it, I get this odd regular popping sound linked above. I am not sure what could be causing this? To hear a clean version go here and hit play:

http://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/

I am just really not good at audio and have no idea what could cause such an odd but consistent distortion (have tried several tones, and music.)

The source is supposed to be 
LR channel
44100 rate

ffmpeg outputs FTLP (Which oddly seems to be in a range >1 and < -1 at times.)
Which I have tried converting by hand and using the resample lib.
I just am not even sure where to start from here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the web-based tone generator you linked to has to do with your recording...

In any case, your recording seems clear that you're getting short buffer underruns.  It's irregular, the pitch stays correct.

> The source is supposed to be LR channel 44100 rate

Perhaps if you could post the actual source somewhere, we could take a look?

> ffmpeg outputs FTLP (Which oddly seems to be in a range >1 and < -1 at times.)

AAC audio works in the frequency domain, not the time domain, and has no concept of integer PCM sample bit depths.  Therefore, the decoder will by default output floating point samples.  It's possible your original source was in floating point as well, and the loudness has carried through, but I'm not sure.  I've never tried any AAC codec with a floating point original.  If it's just a hair over, you're seeing rounding errors at clipping.

> Which I have tried converting by hand and using the resample lib.

Not clear at all what you're trying to resample here...

Comment: The source is an aac-eld raw stream, it decodes successfully. By resample, I meant convert formats: swr_convert_frame.